# Add active_section class to section of menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got an html menu as below...

```html
<ul class="menu" id="menu">
  <ul class='section' id='section_1'>
    <li><span id='section_title_1' class='section_title'><a href='#' id='section_link_1'>Against the odds.</a></span>
      <ul>
        <li id='exhibit_1' class='exhibit_title'><a href="../against-the-odds/introduction"> &rarr; Introduction</a>
        </li>
        <li id='exhibit_2' class='exhibit_title'><a href='../against-the-odds/deriving-functions'> &rarr; Deriving functions</a>
        </li>
        <li id='exhibit_3' class='exhibit_title'><a href='../against-the-odds/exploiting-odds'> &rarr; Exploiting odds</a>
        </li>
        <li id='exhibit_4' class='exhibit_title'><a href='../against-the-odds/betting_history'> &rarr; Betting history</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class='section' id='section_2'>
    <li><span id='section_title_2' class='section_title'><a href='http://themathsproject.co.uk' id='section_link_2'>Remembering everything.</a></span>
      <ul>
        <li id='exhibit_104' class='exhibit_title'><a href='#'>black swans</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class='section' id='section_5'>
    <li><span id='section_title_5' class='section_title'><a href='http://themathsproject.co.uk' id='section_link_5'>Running faster.</a></span>
      <ul>
        <li id='exhibit_107' class='exhibit_title'><a href='#'>possible areas to explore</a>
        </li>
        <li id='exhibit_108' class='exhibit_title'><a href='#'>developing the model</a>
        </li>
        <li id='exhibit_109' class='exhibit_title'><a href='#'>performance</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class='section' id='section_4'>
    <div class='bot'>
      <p><a href='https://www.twitter.com/themathsproject' target="_blank">twitter</a>
        <br />
        <a href='https://www.facebook.com/themathsproject' target="_blank">facebook</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

It's composed of several "sections" which house links (relevant to the section). Each section has a main title (e.g. Against the odds.) and several sub-sections (which are stored in another ul) like "deriving functions". The subsections are set to `display: none` by default (I have jQuery which opens the sub-sections if the user wishes to).

**The problem:**

Once the user clicks on a sub-section link (e.g. www.themathsproject.co.uk/against-the-odds/deriving-functions), I want the sub-section which houses the link (in the case id=section_1) to be open on the page reload so that the user can easily navigate to other links in the section. The other sub-sections would remain closed.

I would like to write a jQuery function which compares the current page url to the links in each section, and, if it finds a match, assign the "active_section" class to the relevant section. Unfortunately, I don't know how to do this.

I've been stuck on this all day and have made little headway.

I would greatly appreciate any help,

Jack

Answer (score 0):

Your post is a little chaotic, so I will try to give you a general tips.

To get last element of your url use

```
var name = window.href.substr(this.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
```

Now you can get all your subsections and iterate over them (for example using jQuery):

```
$('.sub-section').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('id') === name) {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

If your ID's are different than names in url, you can create dictionary to map your equivalents:

```
var sectionMap = { "section-name-1": "sectionID1" };
```

And after you get url using first line of code I have provided, you can do:

```
name = sectionMap[name];
```